# Subform not requerying after combobox change

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I'm currently using Access 2007 to create a form where a combo box filters an editable subform.

The subform is based on a query which takes a Project_ID and from the combo box and filters the subform table based on that Project_ID number. When in form view I am able to change the combo box and after manually refreshing filter the subform. However the subform does not filter automatically with the combo change.

I can't figure out what is going wrong. I've tried multiple VBA variations but nothing works. I am currently using this VBA script after change to lode the subform.

```
Private Sub cboProjectSelect_AfterUpdate()

  Me!Project_Tracker_Subform.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Your current `AfterUpdate` code is merely asking the sub form to requery the existing filter criteria, which will result in the same records being displayed.

In your case, you are wanting to update the subform filter criteria to reference the new value selected in your ComboBox.  To do so, you would need something like this:

```
Dim mssql As String

If Len(Me.cboProjectSelect.Value & "") > 0 Then
    mssql = "[Project_ID] = " & Me.cboProjectSelect.Value
    Me.Project_Tracker_Subform.Form.Filter = mssql
    Me.Project_Tracker_Subform.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
```

This code will only update the subform if a value is chosen in the ComboBox (i.e. if the user clears the ComboBox value, the `If` statement will prevent updating the subform)

Then this code sets your new filter and tells the subform to execute the filter with `FilterOn = True`.

In the case where the user does clear the ComboBox, maybe you would want to remove all filtering from the subform.  In this case, you could add an `Else` clause, such as:

```
Else
    Me.Project_Tracker_Subform.Form.FilterOn = False
End If
```

Comment: That sounds correct. I replicated your code but it still does not seem to work. I'm still getting the issue where the subform will filter based on the combo but I must refresh manually. ** This is the code.
Private Sub cboProjectSelect_AfterUpdate()

Dim mssql As String

If Len(Me.cboProjectSelect.Value & "") > 0 Then

    mssql = "[Project] = " & Me.cboProjectSelect.Value
    Me.Project_Tracker_Subform.Form.Filter = mssql
    Me.Project_Tracker_Subform.Form.FilterOn = True

Else
    Me.Project_Tracker_Subform_(1).Form.FilterOn = False
    
End If**


End Sub

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "the subform will filter based on the combo but I must refresh manually".  Please update your original question with clearer details indicating what records are displayed in the subform when you initially open the form, and what records are displayed after you choose an item in the combobox.